# how to make an image "coming" to foreground

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to show an image and bring it slowly to the foreground (and extend it in the main time). I wish this can be done when I detect the event onmouseover on a div/img.

Currently, I use the hidden attribute but I dislike it because it's like: appear/vanish, without transitions.

I hope there were a solution with a CSS/CSS3 attribute which will do that. But I found none. I try something with the animate. but it hardly failed.

Do somebody know how to do such of thinqs? I'm using basic html/css/js but I can use bootstrap (if it has a good solution).

Thanks.

Comment: show us some code and we can easely extend/renew your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS transition and transform. You could use the scale function. Here's something you can play around to get what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/v2kHU/1/

```
img{
    transition: all 1s;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Edit:

If you want it to be hidden at the beginning then fade in and scale, you could play with the opacity:

http://jsfiddle.net/v2kHU/2/

```
img{
    transition: all 2s;
    opacity:0;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
    opacity:1;
}
```